# How to use MySQL string operation?

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

i want to know how can i  use MySQL string functions on my DB.

I have MySQL db with following like data

```
+---+-----------------------+
|id | name                  |
+---+-----------------------+
| 1 | /sun/steave/xyz       |
| 2 | /mon/alan/asdsas      |
| 3 | /sun/mark/we          |
| 4 | /wed/john/rtd         |
| 5 | /thu/mich/dfgsd       |
+---+-------------------   -+
```

where name is of `type varchar(255)`.

i want to select only **name** i,e (/sun/**steave**/xyz).

i tried like

```
select substr(name,4) from my_table;
```

(i can't use length in `substring`, like `(name,4,6)` because name is dynamic)

which returns me

```
steave/xyz 
alan/asdsas
mark/we
john/rtd
mich/dfgsd
```

How can i select only names from my table?
Is that possible through MySQL string functions?

Comment: Using 'instr()', you can find out, where the '/' is in your remaining string. Together with 'len()' this will allow you to cut out the name. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr (But it would be much better NOT to have multiple data in one database column. Have a look for 'normalization'.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a couple [`substring_index`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) calls to cut your string between the `/`s:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '/', 3), '/', -1)
FROM   my_table
```

EDIT:
As requested in the comments, some more details. To quote the documentation on `substring_index`:

> **SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)** Returns the substring from string `str` before `count` occurrences of the delimiter `delim`. If `count` is positive, everything to the left of the final delimiter (counting from the left) is returned. If `count` is negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter (counting from the right) is returned.

Let's take the string `'/sun/steave/xyz'` as an example. The inner `substring_idex` call returns the substring before the 3rd `/`, so for our case, it returns `'/sun/steave'`. The outer `substring_index` returns the substring after the last `'/'`, so given `'/sun/steave'` it will return just `'steave'`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
can you please add some more explanation  to your answer?
it will be more useful for me like learners. 
thank you.

Comment: @h.APP.y Edited my answer with some explanation, hope that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of

```
select left(right(string.name, length(string.name) - 5), instr( right(string.name, length(string.name) - 5), '/')-1) from (select "/sun/steave/xyz" as name) string
```

will work.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done in XML:

```
SELECT
 MyXML.id
,MyXML.name
,x.value('/NAME[1]/PART[2]','VARCHAR(255)') AS 'PART2'
,x.value('/NAME[1]/PART[3]','VARCHAR(255)') AS 'PART3'
,x.value('/NAME[1]/PART[4]','VARCHAR(255)') AS 'PART4'
FROM (
    SELECT Id, Name
    ,CONVERT(XML,'<NAME><PART>' + REPLACE(Name,'/', '</PART><PART>') + '</PART></NAME>') AS X 
    FROM my_table 
) MyXML
```

Anyway, you should rethink your table structure.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no "with" in MySQL. ( http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16244 ) And using XML to manipulate a string is quite a creative approach in my view.

Comment: @Teetrinker, thanks for your comment, I corrected the code. XML code easier to understand than a cascading functions IMHO.

Comment: I found your approach interesting and wanted to evaluate its performance compared to pure string manipulation and was forced to notice that mysql's convert()-function doesn't do what you assumed. It is meant for character set conversion. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-convert.html Did you even test run your answer?